# How to load CSV file into Apache Kylin

Tags: csv, hive, amazon-emr, kylin

I want to load a csv file that contains >10000000 rows of data into Apache Kylin. Currently, my Kylin (version 3.0.2) is installed in AWS EMR cluster. My csv file is currently stored in s3 bucket. I created the hive table in the EMR and I was able to count all the data by querying 'select count(*) from my_table;, But when I tried to do other specific query, it didn't show the result but just showed OK and the running time.

Then, I tried to load the hive table into Kylin UI. It was successfully loaded and I was able to create the cube for it. However, the cube is 0 GB, but I was able to see all the column names, data type and the file size in the data source.

How can I load the data in the Kylin UI?

Thank you

Comment: Sounds like there is an issue in your cube definition. Try checking if all the parameters are correct in the cube. Also UI doesn't load the data, but the underlying model that defines the data structure.

Comment: So any possible ways that I can query the data in the kylin UI?